# tf_echo error while using fake localization

Tags: ros, fake-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working with erratic robot in gazebo. I have start using fake_localization node. I am facing problem here.
When I try to check the transform by using

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /map /alpha/base_link
```

I got error. When my alpha robot is not moving it shows correct transform. but when robot is moved to another position the transform from /alpha/base_link to /map start giving error. Error I am getting is that some time its giving correct values and some time its giving wrong values. Also I am getting laser scan data and transforming laser detection points to /map frame so it gives error.

Before using fake localization I was working with alpha/odom data and It was working fine.

I am implementing an algorithm to move a robot. first I was using odom data, but now I want to use fake_localization to find the exact position of robot. In my case robot is not publishing odom data, when I try to use fake_localization. Is it my implementation mistake or fake_localization has this kind of behaviour?

suggestions please.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37324/tf_echo-error-while-using-fake-localization/) by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-26**:
Please explain what you are doing.. Otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fake_localization should provide /map->/odom, so you should not get /map->base_link from that unless you misconfigured it manually.
Alternatively someone else is publishing the other transform.

Are you sure there is someone directly doing /map->/base_link? Then disable that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1